# Who are the package maintainers here?

Tags: discussion, community, big-list, package-authors

#### Quick links:

**LaTeX Packages** [**A-M**](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2484), [**N-Z**](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2817)
 ❧ [**LaTeX Classes**](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1182)
 ❧ [**ConTeXt Modules**](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2486)
 ❧ [**Generic Packages**](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2487)
 ❧ [**Support Scripts**](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2488)
 ❧ [**Biblatex Styles**](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2485)

---

A fair few users here have written or maintain packages on CTAN, some even in the TeX Live distribution, or at the least have some official involvement with a package or packages.  I think that it would be useful to have a list of these people, ordered (in some fashion) by package.

My reasoning is twofold.  Firstly, if one of these people answers a question on "their" package, I would hold that answer in higher regard than if Jo User answers it and would be willing to place more confidence in it.  Secondly, if a question turns up that is about that package then it might be useful to know who to nudge about it.

What I most emphatically would not want is that regular people (such as myself) stop answering questions on packages where the maintainer is present - that would be counterproductive - so if people feel that that would happen, please vote to close and delete this!  But if people are willing to try, we could have a single CW answer to this question where people can list the packages that they are connected to (and it should be that people only answer for themselves, not for others).

---

(This question is - rightly - CW and has now been edited so much that the original author is not immediately obvious.  As it was written in the first person and contains opinions, I thought it best to make it clear that the original author was [LoopSpace](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/86/loopspace).)

Comment: How do you want to handle people who write several things, or larger projects (in particular, LaTeX3, but there are others)

Comment: @Alan: "answers by a package maintainer are likely to get up-voted anyway": Yes, but you first have to know that the user _is_ a package maintainer. "It's sometimes even appropriate to mention your status in the answer or a comment": Yes, and some people do, which is good, but it's not good to mention it over and over again. I agree with you, this post here only makes sense for packages with an audience that isn't "too localized".

Comment: @Hendrik: I tend to think that if you suggest one of your own packages when answering a generic question then you really should say '(which I write)' or similar.

Comment: @Joseph: Maybe you're right, and we should make an etiquette out of this. If it's only three words, then it's not too obtrusive. Only that "which I write" sounds a bit strange to me, but I'm not the native speaker here.

Comment: @Hendrik: "maintain" would be a better choice of word.

Comment: @Andrew: Yes, sounds better to me. I just wasn't sure if "which I maintain" is correct grammar.

Comment: @Hendrik, @Andrew: Sounds reasonable. (I mentioned this as occasionally people take 'self-promotion' the wrong way.)

Comment: @Hendrik, Andrew, Joseph: When answering questions about packages I wrote I of course say that I'm the author. However, when I suggest one of my packages as an solution I normally do not, because it is not really relevant, looks like self-promotion and therefore would most likely reduce the answer (make it sound like "Take my package!"), especially when it isn't the first answer. However, if two of my packages are required I normally add the info that they are "from the same author (me)" to highlight that they are compatible and designed to work together.

Comment: @JosephWright: The single answer is getting a little long. Should we maybe at least split it in one answer per category?

Comment: Certain packages are "based on an answer of @EGREG". It is questionable whether the author/maintainer is really a better person to answer than the named Jo User ;-)

Comment: @JosephWright "*How do you want to handle people who write several things, or larger projects (in particular, LaTeX3, but there are others)*". Rely on competent and comprehensive platforms to track contributions (look up a software quality tool called `blame`, by the way). I understand your answer was written in 2011 (sourceforge left a lot to be desired then). Today, I'm sure you can find at least 3 *de facto* and competent standards for such platforms. I can't post answers here, but feel free to probe for more responses from me; I can at least give you "*the right questions*".

Answer (score 59):

### LaTeX Classes

Symbol legend: [image: BitBucket] BitBucket, [image: GitHub] GitHub, [image: Launchpad] Launchpad

- [`achemso`](http://ctan.org/pkg/achemso): [Joseph Wright](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/73/joseph-wright) [image: GitHub]
- [`amsart`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsart): [Barbara Beeton](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/579/barbara-beeton) and others at AMS (`tech-support@ams.org`)
- [`amsbook`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsbook): [Barbara Beeton](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/579/barbara-beeton) and others at AMS (`tech-support@ams.org`)
- [`amsproc`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsproc): [Barbara Beeton](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/579/barbara-beeton) and others at AMS (`tech-support@ams.org`)
- [`aomart`](http://ctan.org/pkg/aomart): [Boris Veytsman](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/5522/boris)
- [`Beamer`](http://ctan.org/pkg/beamer): Vedran Miletić and [Joseph Wright](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/73/joseph-wright)
- [`contracard`](http://ctan.org/pkg/contracard): [Sam Whited](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/10744/sam-whited) [image: GitHub]
- [`ctexart`, `ctexrep` and `ctexbook`](http://ctan.org/pkg/ctex): [Leo Liu](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/2674/leo-liu) and others at [`ctex-kit`](http://code.google.com/p/ctex-kit/).
- [`erdc`](http://ctan.org/pkg/erdc): [Boris Veytsman](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/5522/boris)
- [`estcpmm`](http://ctan.org/pkg/estcpmm): [Boris Veytsman](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/5522/boris)
- [`feupphdteses`](http://ctan.org/pkg/feupphdteses): [Mario S. E.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/27833/mario-s-e)
- [`ijmart`](http://ctan.org/pkg/ijmart): [Boris Veytsman](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/5522/boris)
- [`jmlr`](http://ctan.org/pkg/jmlr): [Nicola Talbot](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/19862/nicola-talbot)
- [`moderncv`](http://ctan.org/pkg/moderncv): [Xavier Danaux](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/10102) [image: Launchpad]
- [`msu-thesis`](http://ctan.org/pkg/msu-thesis): [Alan Munn](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/2693) [image: GitHub]
- [`mugsthesis`](http://ctan.org/pkg/mugsthesis): [Paul Gessler](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/21344) [image: GitHub]
- [`nostarch`](http://ctan.org/pkg/nostarch): [Boris Veytsman](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/5522/boris)
- [`philosophersimprint`](http://ctan.org/pkg/philosophersimprint): [Boris Veytsman](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/5522/boris)
- [`sageep`](http://ctan.org/pkg/sageep): [Boris Veytsman](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/5522/boris)
- [`sesamanuel`](http://ctan.org/pkg/sesamanuel): [Jean-Côme Charpentier](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/142326/jean-c%C3%B4me-charpentier)
- [`skdoc`](http://ctan.org/pkg/skdoc): [Simon Sigurdhsson](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/66) [image: GitHub]
- [`skrapport`](http://ctan.org/pkg/skrapport): [Simon Sigurdhsson](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/66) [image: GitHub]
- [`standalone`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/standalone): [Martin Scharrer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/2975/martin-scharrer) [image: BitBucket]
- [`tkz-doc`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tkz-doc): [Alain Matthes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/3144/altermundus)
- [`tufte-latex`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tufte-latex): [Kevin Godby](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/80/godbyk) [image: GitHub]
- [`yathesis`](http://ctan.org/pkg/yathesis): [Denis Bitouzé](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/18401/denis-bitouz%C3%A9) [image: GitHub]
- [`ydoc`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/ydoc): [Martin Scharrer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/2975/martin-scharrer) [image: BitBucket]

Comment: @OtherPackageAuthors/Maintainers: Please edit this answer to add your own package etc. If you should not have enough reputation (100) to do so feel free to contact one of the [moderators](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about#moderators) or other high rep user to add it for you.

Comment: Can only package authors add themselves, or can we add people who we know are on the site, but may not be reading meta? (e.g. Lars Madsen (memoir), Alain Matthes (tkz-euclide), Herb Voss (pstricks), Philip Kime (biblatex-apa; biber) etc.

Comment: @Alan: I would prefer it if people were at least asked before being put on this list.  One use is so that if there's a relevant question that it seems they didn't spot, their attention can be brought to it.  If they don't want that, they don't have to put their names here.

Comment: @barbara: Thanks for adding yourself to this list.  Whilst it's not technically a package, I think it might be useful to note that you are also the TeX entomologist.  Also, I agree that from the developer's point of view, it's best if bug reports are all sent to the same place, but for users it's not always so clear what is a bug and which package it is to do with.

Comment: For people who use a pseudonym as their user name, should we link to their profiles with the user name (like _Enrico Gregorio [(egreg)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/users/4427/egreg)_) or with their real names (like _[Raphaël Pinson](http://tex.stackexchange.com/users/951/raphink) (Raphink)_)? Or do they have specific reasons to do the one or the other? If not, this bit of consistency might be nice.

Comment: Would it be useful to have a more general list of who is who on TSX? E.g., who's involved with TeX distributions, engines, various utilities, etc.

Comment: @Tomek Sure, go ahead and ask that as a new question, but excluding package authors, who are listed here.

Answer (score 47):

### LaTeX Packages A-L

Symbol legend: [image: BitBucket] BitBucket, [image: GitHub] GitHub, [image: Launchpad] Launchpad, [image: GoogleCode] Google Code, [image: GitLab] GitLab

- [`abc`](//ctan.org/pkg/abc): Enrico Gregorio ([egreg](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/4427))
- [`abraces`](//ctan.org/pkg/abraces): Werner Grundlingh ([Werner](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/5764)) [image: Github]
- [`accents`](//ctan.org/pkg/accents): [Javier Bezos](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/5735)
- [`accsupp`](//ctan.org/pkg/accsupp): [Heiko Oberdiek](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/16967)
- [`acro`](//ctan.org/pkg/acro): Clemens Niederberger ([clemens](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/5049)) [image: BitBucket]
- [`acronym`](//ctan.org/pkg/acronym): [Heiko Oberdiek](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/16967) with Tobias Oetiker
- [`adforn`](//ctan.org/pkg/adforn): [cfr](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/39222) [LaTeX support only]
- [`adfsymbols`](//ctan.org/pkg/adfsymbols): [cfr](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/39222) [LaTeX support only]
- [`adjustbox`](//ctan.org/pkg/adjustbox): [Martin Scharrer](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/2975) [image: BitBucket]
- [`adjmulticol`](//ctan.org/pkg/adjmulticol): [Boris Veytsman](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/5522)
- [`aliascnt`](//ctan.org/pkg/aliascnt): [Heiko Oberdiek](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/16967)
- [`alphalph`](//ctan.org/pkg/alphalph): [Heiko Oberdiek](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/16967)
- [`alterqcm`](//ctan.org/pkg/alterqcm): [Alain Matthes](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/3144)
- [`amsfonts`](//ctan.org/pkg/amsfonts): [Barbara Beeton](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/579) and others at AMS (`tech-support@ams.org`)
- [`amsmath`](//ctan.org/pkg/amsmath): [Barbara Beeton](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/579) and others at AMS (`tech-support@ams.org`)
- [`amsthm`](//ctan.org/pkg/amsthm): [Barbara Beeton](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/579) and others at AMS (`tech-support@ams.org`)
- [`aobs-tikz`](//www.ctan.org/pkg/aobs-tikz): [Claudio Fiandrino](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/13304)
- [`askinclude`](//ctan.org/pkg/askinclude): [Heiko Oberdiek](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/16967) with Pablo Straub
- [`assoccnt`](//ctan.org/pkg/assoccnt): [Christian Hupfer](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/31729)
- [`asypictureB`](//www.ctan.org/pkg/asypictureb): [Charles Staats](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/484)
- [`atbegshi`](//ctan.org/pkg/atbegshi): [Heiko Oberdiek](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/16967)
- [`atenddvi`](//ctan.org/pkg/atenddvi): [Heiko Oberdiek](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/16967)
- [`attachfile2`](//ctan.org/pkg/attachfile2): [Heiko Oberdiek](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/16967)
- [`atveryend`](//ctan.org/pkg/atveryend): [Heiko Oberdiek](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/16967)
- [`autonum`](//ctan.org/pkg/autonum): Patrick Häcker ([MMM](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/7323))
- [`auxhook`](//ctan.org/pkg/auxhook): [Heiko Oberdiek](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/16967)
- [`babyloniannum`](//ctan.org/pkg/babyloniannum): Raphaël Pinson ([ℝaphink](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/951)) [image: GitHub]
- [`background`](//ctan.org/pkg/background): [Gonzalo Medina](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/3954)
- [`backref`](//ctan.org/pkg/backref): [Heiko Oberdiek](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/16967)
- [`baskervaldadf`](//ctan.org/pkg/baskervaldadf): [cfr](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/39222) [LaTeX support only]
- [`berenisadf`](//ctan.org/pkg/berenisadf): [cfr](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/39222) [LaTeX support only]
- [`bibleref`](//ctan.org/pkg/bibleref): [Maïeul Rouquette](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/7712)
- [`bibleref-french`](//ctan.org/pkg/bibleref-french): [Maïeul Rouquette](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/7712) & Raphaël Pinson ([ℝaphink](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/951)) [image: GitHub]
- [`bigintcalc`](//ctan.org/pkg/bigintcalc): : [Heiko Oberdiek](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/16967)
- [`bitset`](//ctan.org/pkg/bitset): [Heiko Oberdiek](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/16967)
- [`blkarray`](//ctan.org/pkg/blkarray): [David Carlisle](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/1090)
- [`bmpsize`](//ctan.org/pkg/bmpsize): [Heiko Oberdiek](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/16967)
- [`bohr`](//ctan.org/pkg/bohr): Clemens Niederberger ([clemens](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/5049)) [image: BitBucket]
- [`bookmark`](//ctan.org/pkg/bookmark): [Heiko Oberdiek](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/16967)
- [`boxhandler`](//ctan.org/pkg/boxhandler): [Steven B. Segletes](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/25858)
- [`braids`](//ctan.org/pkg/braids): Andrew Stacey ([Loop Space](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/86)) [image: GitHub]
- [`cachepic`](//ctan.org/pkg/cachepic): [Tomek](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/5454)
- [`cals`](//www.ctan.org/pkg/cals): Oleg Parashchenko [(olpa)](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/22204) [image: GitHub]
- [`casiofont`](//ctan.org/pkg/casiofont): [Alan Munn](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/2693) [image: GitHub]
- [`catchfile`](//ctan.org/pkg/catchfile): [Heiko Oberdiek](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/16967)
- [`catoptions`](//ctan.org/pkg/catoptions): [Ahmed Musa](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/994)
- [`ccicons`](//ctan.org/pkg/ccicons): [Michael Ummels](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/4087)
- [`censor`](//ctan.org/pkg/censor): [Steven B. Segletes](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/25858)
- [`cfr-lm`](//ctan.org/pkg/cfr-lm): [cfr](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/39222)
- [`chemarr`](//ctan.org/pkg/chemarr): [Heiko Oberdiek](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/16967)
- [`chemfig`](//www.ctan.org/pkg/chemfig): Christian Tellechea ([unbonpetit](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/4164))
- [`chemformula`](//ctan.org/pkg/chemformula): Clemens Niederberger ([clemens](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/5049)) [image: GitHub]
- [`chemgreek`](//ctan.org/pkg/chemgreek): Clemens Niederberger ([clemens](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/5049)) [image: GitHub]
- [`chemmacros`](//ctan.org/pkg/chemmacros): Clemens Niederberger ([clemens](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/5049)) [image: GitHub]
- [`chemnum`](//ctan.org/pkg/chemnum): Clemens Niederberger ([clemens](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/5049)) [image: GitHub]
- [`chemstyle`](//ctan.org/pkg/chemstyle): [Joseph Wright](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/73) [image: BitBucket]
- [`chessboard`](//ctan.org/pkg/chessboard): [Ulrike Fischer](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/2388)
- [`chessfss`](//ctan.org/pkg/chessfss): [Ulrike Fischer](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/2388)
- [`chscite`](//ctan.org/pkg/chscite): [Simon Sigurdhsson](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/66) (technically unmaintained) [image: GitHub]
- [`circuitikz`](//www.ctan.org/pkg/circuitikz): [Massimo Redaelli](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/23842) [image: GitHub], [Romano  Giannetti](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/38080/rmano)
- [`classlist`](//ctan.org/pkg/classlist): [Heiko Oberdiek](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/16967)
- [`clrstrip`](//www.ctan.org/pkg/clrstrip): Jonathan P. Spratte ([Skillmon](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/117050)) [image: GitHub]
- [`cntperchap`](//ctan.org/pkg/cntperchap): [Christian Hupfer](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/31729)
- [`collcell`](//ctan.org/pkg/collcell): [Martin Scharrer](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/2975) [image: BitBucket]
- [`collectbox`](//ctan.org/pkg/collectbox): [Martin Scharrer](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/2975) [image: BitBucket]
- [`colonequals`](//ctan.org/pkg/colonequals): [Heiko Oberdiek](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/16967)
- [`colortbl`](//ctan.org/pkg/colortbl): [David Carlisle](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/1090)
- [`colourchange`](//ctan.org/pkg/colourchange): [Seamus Bradley](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/215)
- [`comma`](//ctan.org/pkg/comma): [David Carlisle](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/1090)
- [`concepts`](//www.ctan.org/pkg/concepts): [Michiel Helvensteijn](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/14886) (mhelvens) [image: Google Code]
- [`contracard`](//ctan.org/pkg/contracard): [Sam Whited](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/10744) [image: GitHub]
- [`crossreftools`](//ctan.org/pkg/crossreftools): [Christian Hupfer](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/31729)
- [`csvsimple`](//ctan.org/pkg/csvsimple): [Thomas F. Sturm](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/30617)
- [`ctex`](//ctan.org/pkg/ctex): [Leo Liu](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/2674) and others at [`ctex-kit`](//code.google.com/p/ctex-kit/)
- [`currfile`](//ctan.org/pkg/currfile): [Martin Scharrer](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/2975) [image: BitBucket]
- [`datatool`](//ctan.org/pkg/datatool): [Nicola Talbot](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/19862)
- [`datetime`](//ctan.org/pkg/datetime): [Nicola Talbot](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/19862)
- [`datetime2`](//ctan.org/pkg/datetime2): [Nicola Talbot](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/19862)
- [`diagbox`](//ctan.org/pkg/diagbox): [Leo Liu](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/2674)
- [`docmute`](//ctan.org/pkg/docmute): [Tomek](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/5454)
- [`doi`](//ctan.org/pkg/doi): [Heiko Oberdiek](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/16967) with Maarten Sneep
- [`doipubmed`](//ctan.org/pkg/doipubmed): [Nicola Talbot](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/19862)
- [`download`](//ctan.org/pkg/download): [Simon Sigurdhsson](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/66) [image: GitHub]
- [`ducksay`](//www.ctan.org/pkg/ducksay): Jonathan P. Spratte ([Skillmon](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/117050)) [image: GitHub]
- [`duckuments`](//www.ctan.org/pkg/duckuments): Jonathan P. Spratte ([Skillmon](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/117050)) [image: GitHub]
- [`dvipscol`](//ctan.org/pkg/dvipscol): [Heiko Oberdiek](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/16967)
- [`easyformat`](//ctan.org/pkg/easyformat): Evert Provoost ([ElecProg](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/129678)) [image: GitHub]
- [`elec­tru­madf`](//ctan.org/pkg/electrumadf): [cfr](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/39222) [LaTeX support only]
- [`eledmac`](//ctan.org/pkg/eledmac): [Maïeul Rouquette](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/7712) [superseded by `reledmac`]
- [`eledpar`](//ctan.org/pkg/eledpar): [Maïeul Rouquette](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/7712) [superseded by `reledpar`]
- [`embedfile`](//ctan.org/pkg/embedfile): [Heiko Oberdiek](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/16967)
- [`embrac`](//ctan.org/pkg/embrac): Clemens Niederberger ([clemens](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/5049)) [image: BitBucket]
- [`endiagram`](//ctan.org/pkg/endiagram): Clemens Niederberger ([clemens](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/5049)) [image: BitBucket]
- [`engord`](//ctan.org/pkg/engord): [Heiko Oberdiek](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/16967)
- [`enparen`](//ctan.org/pkg/enparen): [Heiko Oberdiek](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/16967)
- [`enpassant`](//ctan.org/pkg/enpassant): [Ulrike Fischer](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/2388)
- [`enumitem`](//ctan.org/pkg/enumitem): [Javier Bezos](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/5735)
- [`eolgrab`](//ctan.org/pkg/eolgrab): [Heiko Oberdiek](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/16967)
- [`epstopdf-pkg`](//ctan.org/pkg/epstopdf-pkg): [Heiko Oberdiek](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/16967)
- [`esindex`](//ctan.org/pkg/esindex): [Javier Bezos](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/5735)
- [`etexcmds`](//ctan.org/pkg/etexcmds): [Heiko Oberdiek](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/16967)
- [`etl`](//ctan.org/pkg/etl): Jonathan P. Spratte ([Skillmon](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/117050)) [image: Github]
- [`expkv`](//ctan.org/pkg/expkv): Jonathan P. Spratte ([Skillmon](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/117050)) [image: Github]
- [`expkv-cs`](//ctan.org/pkg/expkv-cs): Jonathan P. Spratte ([Skillmon](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/117050)) [image: Github]
- [`expkv-def`](//ctan.org/pkg/expkv-def): Jonathan P. Spratte ([Skillmon](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/117050)) [image: Github]
- [`expkv-opt`](//ctan.org/pkg/expkv-opt): Jonathan P. Spratte ([Skillmon](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/117050)) [image: Github]
- [`exsheets`](//ctan.org/pkg/exsheets): Clemens Niederberger ([clemens](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/5049)) [image: BitBucket]
- [`fancypar`](//ctan.org/pkg/fancypar): [Gonzalo Medina](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/3954)
- [`fancytabs`](//ctan.org/pkg/fancytabs): Raphaël Pinson ([ℝaphink](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/951)) [image: GitHub]
- [`fdsymbol`](//ctan.org/pkg/fdsymbol): [Michael Ummels](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/4087)
- [`feynmp-auto`](//ctan.org/pkg/feynmp-auto): Enrico Gregorio ([egreg](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/4427))
- [`fibnum`](//ctan.org/pkg/fibnum): [Heiko Oberdiek](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/16967)
- [`filehook`](//ctan.org/pkg/filehook): [Martin Scharrer](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/2975) [image: BitBucket]
- [`filemod`](//ctan.org/pkg/filemod): [Martin Scharrer](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/2975) [image: BitBucket]
- [`fix2col`](//ctan.org/pkg/fix2col): [David Carlisle](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/1090)
- [`fixcmex`](//ctan.org/pkg/fixcmex): Enrico Gregorio ([egreg](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/4427))
- [`fixlatvian`](//ctan.org/pkg/fixlatvian): [Andrey Vihrov](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/3104)
- [`flowfram`](//ctan.org/pkg/flowfram): [Nicola Talbot](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/19862)
- [`fmtcount`](//ctan.org/pkg/fmtcount): [Nicola Talbot](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/19862) and Vincent Belaïche [image: GitHub]
- [`fnpct`](//ctan.org/pkg/fnpct): Clemens Niederberger ([clemens](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/5049)) [image: BitBucket]
- [`fontawesome`](//ctan.org/pkg/fontawesome): [Xavier Danaux](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/10102)
- [`fontbook`](//ctan.org/pkg/fontbook): Raphaël Pinson ([ℝaphink](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/951)) [image: GitHub]
- [`footnotebackref`](//ctan.org/pkg/footnotebackref): Holger Lange ([Holle](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/10570))
- [`forest`](//ctan.org/pkg/forest): [Sašo Živanović](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/16819)
- [`frontespizio`](//ctan.org/pkg/frontespizio): Enrico Gregorio ([egreg](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/4427))
- [`fullwidth`](//ctan.org/pkg/fullwidth): [Marco Daniel](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/5239) [image: GitHub]
- [`gb4e`](//ctan.org/pkg/gb4e): Alexis Dimitriadis ([alexis](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/12092))
- [`genealogytree`](//ctan.org/pkg/genealogytree): [Thomas F. Sturm](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/30617)
- [`gettitlestring`](//ctan.org/pkg/gettitlestring): [Heiko Oberdiek](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/16967)
- [`ghsystem`](//ctan.org/pkg/ghsystem): Clemens Niederberger ([clemens](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/5049)) [image: GitHub]
- [`gincltex`](//ctan.org/pkg/gincltex): [Martin Scharrer](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/2975) [image: BitBucket]
- [`glossaries`](//ctan.org/pkg/glossaries): [Nicola Talbot](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/19862)
- [`glossaries-accsupp`](//ctan.org/pkg/glossaries-accsupp): [Nicola Talbot](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/19862)
- [`gmp`](//ctan.org/pkg/gmp): Enrico Gregorio ([egreg](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/4427))
- [`grabbox`](//www.ctan.org/pkg/grabbox): Jonathan P. Spratte ([Skillmon](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/117050)) ([repository](//gitlass.de/jonathan/grabbox))
- [`grfext`](//ctan.org/pkg/grfext): [Heiko Oberdiek](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/16967)
- [`grffile`](//ctan.org/pkg/grffile): [Heiko Oberdiek](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/16967)
- [`grfpaste`](//ctan.org/pkg/grfpaste): [David Carlisle](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/1090)
- [`he-she`](//ctan.org/pkg/he-she): [Alan Munn](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/2693) [image: GitHub]
- [`hf-tikz`](//www.ctan.org/pkg/hf-tikz): [Claudio Fiandrino](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/13304)
- [`hobby`](//ctan.org/pkg/hobby): Andrew Stacey ([Loop Space](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/86)) [image: GitHub]
- [`hobsub`](//ctan.org/pkg/hobsub): [Heiko Oberdiek](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/16967)
- [`holtxdoc`](//ctan.org/pkg/holtxdoc): [Heiko Oberdiek](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/16967)
- [`hycolor`](//ctan.org/pkg/hycolor): [Heiko Oberdiek](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/16967)
- [`hypatch`](//ctan.org/pkg/hopatch): [Heiko Oberdiek](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/16967)
- [`hypbmsec`](//ctan.org/pkg/hypbmsec): [Heiko Oberdiek](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/16967)
- [`hypcap`](//ctan.org/pkg/hypcap): [Heiko Oberdiek](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/16967)
- [`hypdestopt`](//ctan.org/pkg/hypdestopt): [Heiko Oberdiek](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/16967)
- [`hypdoc`](//ctan.org/pkg/hypdoc): [Heiko Oberdiek](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/16967)
- [`hypgotoe`](//ctan.org/pkg/hypgotoe): [Heiko Oberdiek](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/16967)
- [`hyperref`](//ctan.org/pkg/hyperref): : [Heiko Oberdiek](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/16967) with Sebastian Rahtz
- [`hyphsubst`](//ctan.org/pkg/hyphsubst): [Heiko Oberdiek](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/16967)
- [`idxcmds`](//ctan.org/pkg/idxcmds): Clemens Niederberger ([clemens](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/5049)) [image: BitBucket]
- [`idxlayout`](//ctan.org/pkg/idxlayout): Thomas Titz ([lockstep](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/510))
- [`ifdraft`](//ctan.org/pkg/ifdraft): [Heiko Oberdiek](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/16967)
- [`iflang`](//ctan.org/pkg/iflang): [Heiko Oberdiek](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/16967)
- [`ifluatex`](//ctan.org/pkg/ifluatex): [Heiko Oberdiek](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/16967)
- [`ifoddpage`](//ctan.org/pkg/ifoddpage): [Martin Scharrer](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/2975) [image: BitBucket]
- [`ifpdf`](//ctan.org/pkg/ifpdf): [Heiko Oberdiek](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/16967)
- [`ifvtex`](//ctan.org/pkg/ifvtex): [Heiko Oberdiek](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/16967)
- [`imakeidx`](//ctan.org/pkg/imakeidx): Enrico Gregorio ([egreg](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/4427)) & Claudio Beccari
- [`impnattypo`](//ctan.org/pkg/impnattypo): Raphaël Pinson ([ℝaphink](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/951)) [image: GitHub]
- [`incgraph`](//ctan.org/pkg/incgraph): [Thomas F. Sturm](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/30617)
- [`infwarerr`](//ctan.org/pkg/infwarerr): [Heiko Oberdiek](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/16967)
- [`inputenx`](//ctan.org/pkg/inputenx): [Heiko Oberdiek](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/16967)
- [`intcalc`](//ctan.org/pkg/intcalc): [Heiko Oberdiek](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/16967)
- [`itnumpar`](//ctan.org/pkg/itnumpar): Enrico Gregorio ([egreg](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/4427))
- [`invoice-class`](//ctan.org/pkg/invoice-class): [Alan Munn](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/2693) [image: GitHub]
- [`istgame`](//www.ctan.org/pkg/istgame): [InSung Cho](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/148549)
- [`jigsaw`](//www.ctan.org/pkg/jigsaw): [samcarter](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/36296) [image: GitHub]
- [`jumplines`](//ctan.org/pkg/jumplines): [Christian Hupfer](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/31729)
- [`kantlipsum`](//ctan.org/pkg/kantlipsum): Enrico Gregorio ([egreg](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/4427))
- [`keyreader`](//ctan.org/pkg/keyreader): [Ahmed Musa](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/994)
- [`keyval2e`](//ctan.org/pkg/keyval2e): [Ahmed Musa](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/994)
- [`kvdefinekeys`](//ctan.org/pkg/kvdefinekeys): [Heiko Oberdiek](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/16967)
- [`kvoptions`](//ctan.org/pkg/kvoptions): [Heiko Oberdiek](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/16967)
- [`kvsetkeys`](//ctan.org/pkg/kvsetkeys): [Heiko Oberdiek](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/16967)
- [`latex-tds`](//ctan.org/pkg/latex-tds): [Heiko Oberdiek](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/16967)
- [`leadsheets`](//ctan.org/pkg/leadsheets): Clemens Niederberger ([clemens](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/5049)) [image: GitHub]
- [`ledmac`](//ctan.org/pkg/ledmac): [Maïeul Rouquette](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/7712) [superseded by `reledmac`]
- [`ledpar`](//ctan.org/pkg/ledpar): [Maïeul Rouquette](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/7712) [superseded by `reledpar`]
- [`letltxmacro`](//ctan.org/pkg/letltxmacro): [Heiko Oberdiek](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/16967)
- [`libris`](//ctan.org/pkg/libris): [cfr](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/39222) [LaTeX support only]
- [`lipsum`](//ctan.org/pkg/lipsum): [Phelype Oleinik](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/134574) [image: GitHub]
- [`listingsutf8`](//ctan.org/pkg/listingsutf8): [Heiko Oberdiek](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/16967)
- [`lstaddons`](//ctan.org/pkg/lstaddons) (`lstlinebgrd`, `lstautogobble`): [Martin Scharrer](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/2975/martin-scharrer) [image: BitBucket]
- [`ltxkeys`](//ctan.org/pkg/ltxkeys): [Ahmed Musa](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/994)
- [`ltxtools`](//ctan.org/pkg/ltxtools): [Ahmed Musa](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/994)
- [`lua-check-hyphen`](//ctan.org/pkg/lua-check-hyphen): Patrick Gundlach ([topskip](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/243)) [image: GitHub]
- [`lua-visual-debug`](//ctan.org/pkg/lua-visual-debug): Patrick Gundlach ([topskip](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/243)) [image: GitHub]
- [`luabibentry`](//www.ctan.org/pkg/luabibentry): [Oliver Kopp](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/users/9075) [image: Github]
- [`luacolor`](//ctan.org/pkg/luacolor): [Heiko Oberdiek](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/16967)

Answer (score 35):

### LaTeX Packages M-Z

Symbol legend: [image: BitBucket] BitBucket, [image: GitHub] GitHub, [image: Launchpad] Launchpad, [image: GoogleCode] Google Code, [image: GitLab] GitLab

- [`magicnum`](//ctan.org/pkg/magicnum): [Heiko Oberdiek](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/16967)
- [`makerobust`](//ctan.org/pkg/makerobust): [Heiko Oberdiek](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/16967)
- [`mandi`](//ctan.org/pkg/mandi): [LaTeXereXeTaL](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/218142)
- [`matlab-prettifier`](//www.ctan.org/pkg/matlab-prettifier): [Jubobs](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/21891) [image: Github]
- [`mdframed`](//www.ctan.org/pkg/mdframed): [Marco Daniel](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/5239) [image: GitHub]
- [`menukeys`](//ctan.org/pkg/menukeys): Tobias Weh ([Tobi](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/4918)) [image: GitHub]
- [`metrix`](//ctan.org/pkg/metrix): Tobias Weh ([Tobi](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/4918)) [image: GitHub]
- [`mfirstuc`](//ctan.org/pkg/mfirstuc): [Nicola Talbot](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/19862)
- [`mleftright`](//ctan.org/pkg/mleftright): [Heiko Oberdiek](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/16967)
- [`moderntimeline`](//ctan.org/pkg/moderntimeline): Raphaël Pinson ([ℝaphink](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/951)) [image: GitHub]
- [`modiagram`](//ctan.org/pkg/modiagram): Clemens Niederberger ([clemens](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/5049)) [image: BitBucket]
- [`moreenum`](//ctan.org/pkg/moreenum): [Seamus Bradley](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/215) [image: GitHub]
- [`movement-arrows`](//ctan.org/pkg/movement-arrows):[Alan Munn](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/2693) [image: GitHub]
- [`multienv`](//ctan.org/pkg/multienv): [Martin Scharrer](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/2975) [image: BitBucket]
- [`mwe`](//ctan.org/pkg/mwe): [Martin Scharrer](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/2975) [image: BitBucket]
- [`namedef`](//ctan.org/pkg/namedef): [Phelype Oleinik](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/134574) [image: GitHub]
- [`nameref`](//ctan.org/pkg/nameref): [Heiko Oberdiek](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/16967) with Sebastian Rahtz
- [`newunicodechar`](//ctan.org/pkg/newunicodechar): Enrico Gregorio ([egreg](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/4427))
- [`newverbs`](//ctan.org/pkg/newverbs): [Martin Scharrer](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/2975) [image: BitBucket]
- [`nfssext-cfr`](//ctan.org/pkg/nfssext-cfr): [cfr](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/39222)
- [`noindentafter`](//ctan.org/pkg/noindentafter): Michiel Helvensteijn ([mhelvens](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/14886)) [image: Google Code]
- [`nopageno`](//ctan.org/pkg/nopageno): [David Carlisle](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/1090)
- [`notes2bib`](//ctan.org/pkg/notes2bib): [Joseph Wright](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/73) [image: BitBucket]
- [`nowidow`](//ctan.org/pkg/nowidow): Raphaël Pinson ([ℝaphink](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/951)) [image: GitHub]
- [`ocgx`](//ctan.org/pkg/ocgx): [Paul Gaborit](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/14500) [image: GitHub]
- [`octave`](//ctan.org/pkg/octave): Andrew Cashner ([musarithmia](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/56233)) [image: BitBucket]
- [`odsfile`](//ctan.org/pkg/odsfile): Michal Hoftich [michal.h21](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/2891) [image: GitHub]
- [`pagesgrid`](//ctan.org/pkg/pagegrid): [Heiko Oberdiek](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/16967)
- [`pagesel`](//ctan.org/pkg/pagesel): [Heiko Oberdiek](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/16967)
- [`pax`](//ctan.org/pkg/pax): [Heiko Oberdiek](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/16967)
- [`pdfcol`](//ctan.org/pkg/pdfcol): [Heiko Oberdiek](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/16967)
- [`pdfcolfoot`](//ctan.org/pkg/pdfcolfoot): [Heiko Oberdiek](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/16967)
- [`pdfcolmk`](//ctan.org/pkg/pdfcolmk): [Heiko Oberdiek](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/16967)
- [`pdfcolparallel`](//ctan.org/pkg/pdfcolparallel): [Heiko Oberdiek](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/16967)
- [`pdfcolparcolumns`](//ctan.org/pkg/pdfcolparcolumns): [Heiko Oberdiek](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/16967)
- [`pdfcomment`](//ctan.org/pkg/pdfcomment): Josef Kleber ([Josef](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/3190)) [image: BitBucket]
- [`pdfcrypt`](//ctan.org/pkg/pdfcrypt): [Heiko Oberdiek](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/16967)
- [`pdfescape`](//ctan.org/pkg/pdfescape): [Heiko Oberdiek](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/16967)
- [`pdflscape`](//ctan.org/pkg/pdflscape): [Heiko Oberdiek](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/16967)
- [`pdfoverlay`](//ctan.org/pkg/pdfoverlay): [David Purton](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/87678) [image: GitHub]
- [`pdfpages`](//ctan.org/pkg/pdfpages): [Andreas Matthias](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/80551)
- [`pdfrender`](//ctan.org/pkg/pdfrender): [Heiko Oberdiek](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/16967)
- [`pdftex-def`](//ctan.org/pkg/pdftex-def): [Heiko Oberdiek](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/16967) & [Martin Schröder](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/5763) with [David Carlisle](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/1090), Sebastian Rahtz & Hans Hagen
- [`pdftexcmds`](//ctan.org/pkg/pdftexcmds): [Heiko Oberdiek](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/16967)
- [`pgfkeyx`](//ctan.org/pkg/pgfkeyx): [Ahmed Musa](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/994)
- [`pgfmath-xfp`](//www.ctan.org/pkg/pgfmath-xfp): Jonathan P. Spratte ([Skillmon](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/117050)) [image: GitHub]
- [`pgfplots`](//ctan.org/pkg/pgfplots): [Christian Feuersaenger](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/1537)
- [`pgfplotstable`](//ctan.org/pkg/pgfplotstable): [Christian Feuersaenger](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/1537)
- [`physymb`](//ctan.org/pkg/physymb): [David Zaslavsky](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/125)
- [`picture`](//ctan.org/pkg/picture): [Heiko Oberdiek](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/16967)
- [`pkfix`](//ctan.org/pkg/pkfix): [Heiko Oberdiek](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/16967)
- [`pmboxdraw`](//ctan.org/pkg/pmboxdraw): [Heiko Oberdiek](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/16967)
- [`PoetryTeX`](//ctan.org/pkg/poetrytex): [Sam Whited](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/10744) [image: GitHub]
- [`probsoln`](//ctan.org/pkg/probsoln): [Nicola Talbot](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/19862)
- [`protecteddef`](//ctan.org/pkg/protecteddef): [Heiko Oberdiek](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/16967)
- [`pslatex`](//ctan.org/pkg/pslatex): [David Carlisle](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/1090)
- [`pspicture`](//ctan.org/pkg/pspicture): [David Carlisle](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/1090)
- [`pst-pdgr`](//ctan.org/pkg/pst-pdgr): [Boris Veytsman](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/5522)
- [`pst-vowel`](//ctan.org/pkg/pst-vowel): [Alan Munn](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/2693) [image: GitHub]
- [`pxpic`](//ctan.org/pkg/pxpic): Jonathan P. Spratte ([Skillmon](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/117050)) [image: Github]
- [`qtree`](//ctan.org/pkg/qtree): Alexis Dimitriadis ([alexis](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/12092))
- [`quoting`](//ctan.org/pkg/quoting): Thomas Titz ([lockstep](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/510))
- [`ragged2e`](//ctan.org/pkg/ragged2e): [Martin Schröder](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/5763)
- [`raleway`](//ctan.org/pkg/raleway): Silke Hofstra ([Silex](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/17484))
- [`recorder-fingering`](//ctan.org/pkg/recorder-fingering): [Alan Munn](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/2693) [image: Github]
- [`refcount`](//ctan.org/pkg/refcount): [Heiko Oberdiek](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/16967)
- [`rerunfilecheck`](//ctan.org/pkg/rerunfilecheck): [Heiko Oberdiek](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/16967)
- [`resizegather`](//ctan.org/pkg/resizegather): [Heiko Oberdiek](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/16967)
- [`rcs-multi`](//ctan.org/pkg/rcs-multi): [Martin Scharrer](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/2975) [image: BitBucket]
- [`realboxes`](//ctan.org/pkg/realboxes): [Martin Scharrer](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/2975) [image: BitBucket]
- [`refenums`](//ctan.org/pkg/refenums): [Oliver Kopp](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/9075) [image: Github]
- [`reledmac`](//ctan.org/pkg/reledmac): [Maïeul Rouquette](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/7712) [image: GitHub]
- [`reledpar`](//ctan.org/pkg/reledpar): [Maïeul Rouquette](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/7712) [image: GitHub]
- [`romandeadf`](//ctan.org/pkg/romandeadf): [cfr](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/39222) [LaTeX support only]
- [`rotchiffre`](//ctan.org/pkg/rotchiffre): [Heiko Oberdiek](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/16967)
- [`rviewport`](//ctan.org/pkg/rviewport): [Boris Veytsman](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/5522)
- [`sa-tikz`](//ctan.org/pkg/sa-tikz): [Claudio Fiandrino](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/13304) [image: Github]
- [`scalerel`](//ctan.org/pkg/scalerel): [Steven B. Segletes](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/25858)
- [`scontents`](//ctan.org/pkg/scontents): [Pablo González L](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/7832) [image: Github]
- [`sclang-prettifier`](//ctan.org/pkg/sclang-prettifier): [Jubobs](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/21891) [image: Github]
- [`screenplay-pkg`](//ctan.org/pkg/screenplay-pkg):[Alan Munn](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/2693)
- [`scrindex`](//ctan.org/pkg/scrindex): [Heiko Oberdiek](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/16967)
- [`selinput`](//ctan.org/pkg/selinput): [Heiko Oberdiek](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/16967)
- [`selnolig`](//ctan.org/pkg/selnolig): [Mico Loretan](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/5001)
- [`semantic-markup`](//ctan.org/pkg/semantic-markup): Andrew Cashner ([musarithmia](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/56233)) [image: BitBucket]
- [`seqsplit`](//ctan.org/pkg/seqsplit): [Boris Veytsman](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/5522)
- [`setouterhbox`](//ctan.org/pkg/setouterhbox): [Heiko Oberdiek](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/16967)
- [`settobox`](//ctan.org/pkg/settobox): [Heiko Oberdiek](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/16967)
- [`showhyphens`](//ctan.org/pkg/showhyphens): Patrick Gundlach ([topskip](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/243))
- [`siunitx`](//ctan.org/pkg/siunitx): [Joseph Wright](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/73) [image: BitBucket]
- [`skeycommand`](//ctan.org/pkg/skeycommand): [Ahmed Musa](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/994)
- [`skmath`](//ctan.org/pkg/skmath): [Simon Sigurdhsson](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/66) [image: GitHub]
- [`smartdiagram`](//ctan.org/pkg/smartdiagram): [Claudio Fiandrino](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/13304)
- [`soulutf8`](//ctan.org/pkg/soulutf8): [Heiko Oberdiek](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/16967)
- [`sourcecodepro`](//ctan.org/pkg/sourcecodepro): Silke Hofstra ([Silex](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/17484))
- [`sourcesanspro`](//ctan.org/pkg/sourcesanspro): Silke Hofstra ([Silex](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/17484))
- [`spath3`](//ctan.org/pkg/spath3):  Andrew Stacey ([Loop Space](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/86)) [image: GitHub]
- [`spreadtab`](//ctan.org/pkg/spreadtab):  Christian Tellechea ([unbonpetit](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/4164))
- [`stackrel`](//ctan.org/pkg/stackrel): [Heiko Oberdiek](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/16967)
- [`stampinclude`](//ctan.org/pkg/stampinclude): [Heiko Oberdiek](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/16967)
- [`standalone`](//ctan.org/pkg/standalone): [Martin Scharrer](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/2975) [image: BitBucket]
- [`steinmetz`](//ctan.org/pkg/steinmetz): Enrico Gregorio ([egreg](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/4427))
- [`storebox`](//ctan.org/pkg/storebox): [Martin Scharrer](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/2975) [image: BitBucket]
- [`storecmd`](//ctan.org/pkg/storecmd): [Ahmed Musa](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/994)
- [`stringenc`](//ctan.org/pkg/stringenc): [Heiko Oberdiek](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/16967)
- [`stringstrings`](//ctan.org/pkg/stringstrings): [Steven B. Segletes](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/25858)
- [`subfiles`](//ctan.org/pkg/subfiles): Gernot Salzer [gernot](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/110998) [image: GitHub]
- [`substances`](//ctan.org/pkg/substances): Clemens Niederberger ([clemens](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/5049)) [image: BitBucket]
- [`svn-multi`](//ctan.org/pkg/svn-multi): [Martin Scharrer](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/2975) [image: BitBucket]
- [`svn-prov`](//ctan.org/pkg/svn-prov): [Martin Scharrer](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/2975) [image: BitBucket]
- [`tabularcalc`](//ctan.org/pkg/tabularcalc): Christian Tellechea ([unbonpetit](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/4164/unbonpetit))
- [`tabularht`](//ctan.org/pkg/tabularht): [Heiko Oberdiek](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/16967)
- [`tabularkv`](//ctan.org/pkg/tabularkv): [Heiko Oberdiek](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/16967)
- [`tabulary`](//ctan.org/pkg/tabulary): [David Carlisle](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/1090)
- [`tcolorbox`](//ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox): [Thomas F. Sturm](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/30617)
- [`telprint`](//ctan.org/pkg/telprint): [Heiko Oberdiek](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/16967)
- [`tensind`](//ctan.org/pkg/tensind): [Javier Bezos](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/5735)
- [`textcase`](//ctan.org/pkg/textcase): [David Carlisle](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/1090)
- [`thepdfnumber`](//ctan.org/pkg/thepdfnumber): [Heiko Oberdiek](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/16967)
- [`thmtools`](//ctan.org/pkg/thmtools): [Ulrich Schwarz](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/1860)
- [`thumbpdf`](//ctan.org/pkg/thumbpdf): [Heiko Oberdiek](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/16967)
- [`tikz-among-us`](//ctan.org/pkg/tikz-among-us): Fernando H. G. Zucatelli ([FHZ](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/140133))
- [`tikz-feynman`](//ctan.org/pkg/tikz-feynman): Joshua Ellis ([JP-Ellis](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/26980)) [image: Github]
- [`tikz-timing`](//ctan.org/pkg/tikz-timing): [Martin Scharrer](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/2975) [image: BitBucket]
- [`tikzducks`](//ctan.org/pkg/tikzducks): [samcarter](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/36296) [image: GitHub]
- [`tikzlings`](//ctan.org/pkg/tikzlings): [samcarter](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/36296) [image: GitHub]
- [`tikzmark`](//ctan.org/pkg/tikzmark):  Andrew Stacey ([Loop Space](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/86)) [image: GitHub]
- [`tikzmarmots`](//ctan.org/pkg/tikzmarmots): [samcarter](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/36296) [image: GitHub]
- [`tikzpagenodes`](//ctan.org/pkg/tikzpagenodes): [Martin Scharrer](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/2975) [image: BitBucket]
- [`tikzscale`](//ctan.org/pkg/tikzscale): Patrick Häcker ([MMM](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/7323))
- [`titleps`](//ctan.org/pkg/titleps): [Javier Bezos](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/5735)
- [`titlesec`](//ctan.org/pkg/titlesec): [Javier Bezos](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/5735)
- [`titletoc`](//ctan.org/pkg/titletoc): [Javier Bezos](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/5735)
- [`tkz-base`](//ctan.org/pkg/tkz-base): [Alain Matthes](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/3144)
- [`tkz-berge`](//ctan.org/pkg/tkz-berge): [Alain Matthes](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/3144)
- [`tkz-euclide`](//ctan.org/pkg/tkz-euclide): [Alain Matthes](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/3144)
- [`tkz-fct`](//ctan.org/pkg/tkz-fct): [Alain Matthes](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/3144)
- [`tkz-graph`](//ctan.org/pkg/tkz-graph): [Alain Matthes](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/3144)
- [`tkz-kiviat`](//ctan.org/pkg/tkz-kiviat): [Alain Matthes](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/3144)
- [`tkz-linknodes`](//ctan.org/pkg/tkz-linknodes): [Alain Matthes](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/3144)
- [`tkz-tab`](//ctan.org/pkg/tkz-tab): [Alain Matthes](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/3144)
- [`tqft`](//ctan.org/pkg/tqft): Andrew Stacey ([Loop Space](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/86)) [image: GitHub]
- [`translations`](//ctan.org/pkg/translations): Clemens Niederberger ([clemens](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/5049)) [image: GitHub]
- [`transparent`](//ctan.org/pkg/transparent): [Heiko Oberdiek](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/16967)
- [`twoopt`](//ctan.org/pkg/twoopt): [Heiko Oberdiek](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/16967)
- [`type1cm`](//ctan.org/pkg/type1cm): [David Carlisle](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/1090)
- [`typehtml`](//ctan.org/pkg/typehtml): [David Carlisle](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/1090)
- [`tzplot`](//www.ctan.org/pkg/tzplot): [InSung Cho](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/148549)
- [`underoverlap`](//ctan.org/pkg/underoverlap): Michiel Helvensteijn ([mhelvens](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/14886)) [image: Google Code]
- [`uniquecounter`](//ctan.org/pkg/uniquecounter): [Heiko Oberdiek](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/16967)
- [`usebib`](//ctan.org/pkg/usebib): Enrico Gregorio ([egreg](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/4427))
- [`venndiagram`](//ctan.org/pkg/venndiagram): [Nicola Talbot](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/19862)
- [`venturisadf`](//ctan.org/pkg/venturisadf): [cfr](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/39222) [LaTeX support only]
- [`verbatimbox`](//ctan.org/pkg/verbatimbox): [Steven B. Segletes](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/25858)
- [`vpe`](//ctan.org/pkg/vpe): [Heiko Oberdiek](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/16967)
- [`withargs`](//ctan.org/pkg/withargs): Michiel Helvensteijn ([mhelvens](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/14886)) [image: GitHub]
- [`xassoccnt`](//ctan.org/pkg/xassoccnt): [Christian Hupfer](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/31729)
- [`xcite`](//ctan.org/pkg/xcite): Enrico Gregorio ([egreg](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/4427))
- [`xcntperchap`](//ctan.org/pkg/xcntperchap): [Christian Hupfer](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/31729)
- [`xeCJK`](//ctan.org/pkg/xecjk): [Leo Liu](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/2674) and Qing Lee.
- [`xfor`](//ctan.org/pkg/xfor): [Nicola Talbot](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/19862)
- [`xistercian`](//ctan.org/pkg/xistercian): Jonathan P. Spratte ([Skillmon](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/117050)) [image: Github]
- [`xlop`](//ctan.org/pkg/xlop): [Jean-Côme Charpentier](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/142326)
- [`xskak`](//ctan.org/pkg/xskak): [Ulrike Fischer](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/2388)
- [`xpatch`](//ctan.org/pkg/xpatch): Enrico Gregorio ([egreg](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/4427))
- [`xpeek`](//ctan.org/pkg/xpeek): [Joel C. Salomon](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/2966) [image: GitHub]
- [`xsim`](//ctan.org/pkg/xsim): Clemens Niederberger ([clemens](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/5049)) [image: GitGub]
- [`xwatermark`](//ctan.org/pkg/xwatermark): [Ahmed Musa](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/994)
- [`ydoc`](//ctan.org/pkg/ydoc): [Martin Scharrer](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/2975) [image: BitBucket]
- [`ytableau`](//ctan.org/pkg/ytableau): [Ryan Reich](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/575)
- [`zhmCJK`](//ctan.org/pkg/zhmcjk): [Leo Liu](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/2674)
- [`zref`](//ctan.org/pkg/zref): [Heiko Oberdiek](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/16967)

Answer (score 28):

### Support Scripts

Symbol legend: [image: BitBucket] BitBucket, [image: GitHub] GitHub, [image: Launchpad] Launchpad

- [`arara`](http://ctan.org/pkg/arara): [Paulo Cereda](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/3094), [Marco Daniel](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/5239), [Nicola Talbot](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/19862/nicola-talbot) and [Brent Longborough](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/344) [image: GitHub]
- [`bib2gls`](http://ctan.org/pkg/bib2gls): [Nicola Talbot](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/19862/nicola-talbot) [image: GitHub]
- [`checkcites`](http://ctan.org/pkg/checkcites): Enrico Gregorio [(egreg)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/4427) and [Paulo Cereda](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/3094) [image: GitHub]
- [`check-parens`](http://ctan.org/pkg/check-parens): Jaap Eldering [(eldering)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/4131)
- [`csv2latex`](http://ctan.org/pkg/csv2latex): [Alan Munn](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/2693) [image: GitHub]
- [`ctanupload`](http://ctan.org/pkg/ctanupload): [Martin Scharrer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/2975/martin-scharrer) [image: BitBucket]
- [`dosepsbin`](http://ctan.org/pkg/dosepsbin): [Heiko Oberdiek](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/16967/heiko-oberdiek)
- [`jmakepdfx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/jmakepdfx): [Nicola Talbot](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/19862/nicola-talbot)
- [`jpgfdraw`](http://ctan.org/pkg/jpgfdraw): [Nicola Talbot](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/19862/nicola-talbot)
- [`(la)texdef`](http://ctan.org/pkg/texdef): [Martin Scharrer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/2975/martin-scharrer) [image: BitBucket]
- [`latexindent`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/latexindent): [Chris Hughes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/6621/cmhughes) [image: GitHub]
- [`latexmk`](http://ctan.org/pkg/latexmk): [John Collins](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/8495/john-collins)
- [`ltximg`](https://ctan.org/pkg/ltximg): [Pablo González L](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/7832/pablo-gonz%C3%A1lez-l) [image: Github]
- [`makedtx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/makedtx): [Nicola Talbot](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/19862/nicola-talbot)
- [`makeglossariesgui`](http://ctan.org/pkg/makeglossariesgui): [Nicola Talbot](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/19862/nicola-talbot)
- [`mkjobtexmf`](http://ctan.org/pkg/mkjobtexmf): [Heiko Oberdiek](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/16967/heiko-oberdiek)
- [`pdfcrop`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pdfcrop): [Heiko Oberdiek](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/16967/heiko-oberdiek)
- [`pedigree-perl`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pedigree-perl): [Boris Veytsman](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/5522/boris)
- [`sty2dtx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/sty2dtx): [Martin Scharrer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/2975/martin-scharrer) [image: BitBucket]

Answer (score 25):

### Biblatex Styles

Symbol legend: [image: BitBucket] BitBucket, [image: GitHub] GitHub, [image: Launchpad] Launchpad

- [`biblatex-chem`](http://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-chem): [Joseph Wright](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/73/joseph-wright) [image: BitBucket]
- [`biblatex-phys`](http://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-phys): [Joseph Wright](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/73/joseph-wright) [image: BitBucket]
- [`biblatex-ieee`](http://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-ieee): [Joseph Wright](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/73/joseph-wright) [image: BitBucket]
- [`biblatex-musuos`](http://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-musuos): Tobias Weh ([Tobi](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/4918/tobi))
- [`biblatex-nature`](http://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-nature): [Joseph Wright](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/73/joseph-wright) [image: BitBucket]
- [`biblatex-nejm`](http://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-nejm): [Marco Daniel](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/5239/marco) [image: GitHub]
- [`biblatex-publist`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-publist): [Jür­gen Spitzmüller](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/19291/jspitzm) [image: GitHub]
- [`biblatex-sbl`](http://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-sbl): [David Purton](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/87678/david-purton) [image: GitHub]
- [`biblatex-trad`](http://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-trad): [Marco Daniel](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/5239/marco) [image: GitHub]

Answer (score 24):

### Generic Packages

Symbol legend: [image: BitBucket] BitBucket, [image: GitHub] GitHub, [image: Launchpad] Launchpad

- [`apnum.tex`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/apnum): Petr Olšák ([wipet](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/51799/))
- [`asapsym`](http://ctan.org/pkg/asapsym): [Paul Gessler](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/21344) [image: GitHub]
- [`chemfig.tex`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/chemfig): Christian Tellechea ([unbonpetit](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/4164/unbonpetit))
- [`cnv.tex`](ftp://math.feld.cvut.cz/pub/olsak/makra/cnv.tex): Petr Olšák ([wipet](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/51799/))
- [`code128, ean13`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/code128) Petr Olšák ([wipet](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/51799/))
- [`csplain (+opmac)`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/csplain): Petr Olšák ([wipet](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/51799/))
- [`ctustyle, custyle`](http://petr.olsak.net/ctustyle-e.html): Petr Olšák ([wipet](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/51799/))
- [`dirtree`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/dirtree): [Jean-Côme Charpentier](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/142326/jean-c%C3%B4me-charpentier)
- [`docbytex`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/docbytex): Petr Olšák ([wipet](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/51799/))
- [`encTeX`](http://www.olsak.net/enctex.html): Petr Olšák ([wipet](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/51799/))
- [`expkv`](//ctan.org/pkg/expkv): Jonathan P. Spratte ([Skillmon](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/117050)) [image: Github]
- [`expkv-cs`](//ctan.org/pkg/expkv-cs): Jonathan P. Spratte ([Skillmon](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/117050)) [image: Github]
- [`expkv-def`](//ctan.org/pkg/expkv-def): Jonathan P. Spratte ([Skillmon](//tex.stackexchange.com/users/117050)) [image: Github]
- [`filemod.tex`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/filemod): [Martin Scharrer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/2975/martin-scharrer) [image: BitBucket]
- [`ofs.tex`](http://petr.olsak.net/ofs.html): Petr Olšák ([wipet](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/51799/))
- [`pgfplots`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pgfplots): [Christian Feuersaenger](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/1537)
- [`pst-infixplot`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pst-infixplot): [Jean-Côme Charpentier](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/142326/jean-c%C3%B4me-charpentier) and Christophe Jorssen
- [`qrcode.tex`](ftp://math.feld.cvut.cz/pub/olsak/makra/qrcode.tex): Petr Olšák ([wipet](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/51799/))
- [`randomlist`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/randomlist): Christian Tellechea ([unbonpetit](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/4164/unbonpetit)) and [Jean-Côme Charpentier](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/142326/jean-c%C3%B4me-charpentier)
- [`scancsv.tex`](ftp://math.feld.cvut.cz/pub/olsak/makra/scancsv.tex): Petr Olšák ([wipet](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/51799/))
- [`systeme.tex`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/systeme): Christian Tellechea ([unbonpetit](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/4164/unbonpetit))
- [`tracklang`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tracklang): [Nicola Talbot](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/19862/nicola-talbot)
- [`xstring.tex`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/xstring): Christian Tellechea ([unbonpetit](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/4164/unbonpetit))
- [`ydocstrip.tex`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/ydoc): [Martin Scharrer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/2975/martin-scharrer) [image: BitBucket]
- [`xmltex`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/xmltex): [David Carlisle](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/1090/david-carlisle)
- [`xlop`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/xlop): [Jean-Côme Charpentier](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/142326/jean-c%C3%B4me-charpentier)
- [`ZzTEX`](https://ctan.org/pkg/zztex): [Paul C. Anagnostopoulos](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/183513/paul-c-anagnostopoulos)

Answer (score 20):

### ConTeXt Modules

Symbol legend: [image: GitHub] GitHub

- [`filter`](http://modules.contextgarden.net/filter): [Aditya Mahajan](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/323/aditya) [image: GitHub]
- [`gnuplot`](http://modules.contextgarden.net/gnuplot): [Mojca Miklavec](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/6367/mojca-miklavec) [image: GitHub]
- [`letterine`](http://modules.contextgarden.net/t-lettrine): [Taco Hoekwater](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/89/taco-hoekwater)
- [`mathsets`](http://modules.contextgarden.net/mathsets): [Aditya Mahajan](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/323/aditya) [image: GitHub]
- [`simpleslides`](http://modules.contextgarden.net/simpleslides): Thomas Schmitz and [Aditya Mahajan](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/323/aditya)
- [`vim`](http://modules.contextgarden.net/vim): [Aditya Mahajan](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/323/aditya) [image: GitHub]
- [`visualcounter`](http://modules.contextgarden.net/visualcounter): [Aditya Mahajan](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/323/aditya) [image: GitHub]