# Who are the book authors here?

Tags: discussion, community, big-list

Some people of this community [write packages](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1181/who-are-the-package-maintainers-here) but there are also those that write books. Therefore I ask, what community members have written books on TeX and friends?

(One answer per book or series of related books. Include whatever detail seems appropriate.)

Comment: @Forgiver This is as hard to tell for sure since like for any other question one do not have give reasons for voting. My guess is that the votes shows which books is the most recognized.

Answer (score 18):

## [Stefan Kottwitz](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/213/stefan-kottwitz)

[*LaTeX Beginner's Guide*](http://link.packtpub.com/lOKssB)

[image: LaTeX Beginner's Guide]

Comment: you can add your cookbook ;-)

Answer (score 16):

## [Frank Mittelbach](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/10109/frank-mittelbach)

1. [*LaTeX Graphics Companion*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0321508920)

   [image]
2. [*The LaTeX Companion*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0201362996)

   [image]
3. [*Der Latex Begleiter*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/3827370442) (in German)

   [image]

Answer (score 15):

## [Marc van Dongen](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/10274/marc-van-dongen)

[*LaTeX and Friends*](http://www.springerlink.com/content/978-3-642-23816-1)

[image: LaTeX and Friends]

Comment: Also see the author's [book website](http://csweb.ucc.ie/~dongen/LAF/LAF.html) for additional resource.

Answer (score 14):

## [Herbert Voss](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/2478/herbert)

1. [*PSTricks: Graphics and PostScript for TeX and LaTeX*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1906860130) (in English)

   [image: PSTricks: Graphics and PostScript for TeX and LaTeX]
2. [*Typesetting Mathematics with LaTeX*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1906860173) (in English)

   [image: Typesetting Mathematics with LaTeX]
3. [*LaTeX Quick Reference*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1906860211) (in English)

   [image: LaTeX Quick Reference]
4. [*Typesetting tables with LaTeX*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1906860254) (in English)

   [image: Typesetting tables with LaTeX]
5. [*Tabellen mit LaTeX*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/3865413706) (in German)

   [image: Tabellen mit LaTeX]
6. [*PSTricks*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/3865414036) (in German)

   [image: Tabellen mit LaTeX]
7. [*Bibliografien mit LaTeX*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/386541415X) (in German)

   [image: Bibliografien mit LaTeX]
8. [*Einführung in LaTeX*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/3865414621) (in German)

   [image: Einführung in LaTeX]

Comment: DANTE members get a discount on (some of?) the books that have the DANTE logo on the bottom right of the cover page.

Comment: My university library just got PSTricks book which I ordered two months ago. I am not sure that a novice user of PSTricks can learn anything from the book but my knowledge grow exponentially. I immediately ordered three other English titles for our library. Money well spent:) Dr. Voss has done a great service to TeX and in particular to PSTricks community by writing PSTricks monography and I would like publicly to thank him for the effort. Truly magnificent work to document PSTricks family of packages.

Answer (score 7):

## [Nicola Talbot](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/19862/nicola-talbot)

[LaTeX for Complete Novices](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/novices/)

[image: book image]

[Using LaTeX to Write a PhD Thesis](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/thesis/)

[image: book image]

[LaTeX for Administrative Work](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/admin/)

[image: book image]