# Who has a GitHub, Bitbucket, other code profile?

Tags: discussion, community, big-list

In the style of [`Who are the package maintainers here?`](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1181/who-are-the-package-maintainers-here/) and other [big-list](/questions/tagged/big-list) questions, I was wondering who here (package maintainer or no) has a GitHub, Bitbucket, CTAN author page, Launchpad, or other place where they keep a portfolio of their code (some of which is bound to be TeX in this community)?

This stems from a discussion on chat in which [`cgnieder`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/5049/cgnieder) and [`PauloCereda`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/3094/paulo-cereda) were following all TeX.SE people on GitHub.

Hopefully this list can become a place where people can go when looking for examples (eg. if a member answers lots of [lilypond](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lilypond) questions you might check out their GitHub and see if they've got any samples), or to learn a bit more about the various people on this site, their backgrounds, etc.

Please edit the CW answer below to add yourself to the list.

Comment: What is the Objective of this post apart from the `package maintainers post`: Bringing `Prospective` Package TeX code developers together for sharing ? if possible can you add the motive in Q to draw wide attention

Comment: I don't know if other's like to share links here by someone else , but search like [this](http://chat.stackexchange.com/search?q=github&room=41) or [this](http://chat.stackexchange.com/search?q=bitbucket&user=&room=41) could give some idea etc..

Comment: @texenthusiast I'm not sure what the protocol on sharing links by someone else is; I'd say just let them put it in the list if they want to. RE: motivation, that's a great idea; I'll add something along those lines.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

**Legend:**

- [image: Assembla] *Assembla*
- [image: BitBucket] *BitBucket*
- [image: CTAN] *CTAN*
- [image: GitHub] *GitHub*
- [image: LaTeX2e] *LaTeX2e*
- [image: LaTeX3] *LaTeX3*
- [image: SourceForge] *SourceForge*
- [image: Empty] *Not applicable*

### Code corpus

- [image: Empty]
  [image: Empty]
  [image: Empty]
  [image: GitHub]
  [image: Empty]
  [image: Empty]
  [image: Empty]
  :: [Sean Allred](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/17423/sean-allred)
- [image: Empty]
  [image: BitBucket]
  [image: CTAN]
  [image: GitHub]
  [image: Empty]
  [image: Empty]
  [image: Empty]
  :: [Andrew Cashner](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/56233/andrew-cashner) (musarithmia)
- [image: Empty]
  [image: Empty]
  [image: CTAN]
  [image: GitHub]
  [image: LaTeX2e]
  [image: LaTeX3]
  [image: SourceForge]
  :: [David Carlisle](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/1090/david-carlisle)
- [image: Empty]
  [image: Empty]
  [image: Empty]
  [image: GitHub]
  [image: Empty]
  [image: Empty]
  [image: Empty]
  :: [dustin](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/27081/dustin)
- [image: Empty]
  [image: BitBucket]
  [image: CTAN]
  [image: GitHub]
  [image: Empty]
  [image: Empty]
  [image: SourceForge]
  :: [Paulo Cereda](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/3094)
- [image: Empty]
  [image: Empty]
  [image: CTAN]
  [image: GitHub]
  [image: Empty]
  [image: Empty]
  [image: Empty]
  :: [Claudio Fiandrino](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/13304/claudio-fiandrino)
- [image: Empty]
  [image: Empty]
  [image: CTAN]
  [image: Empty]
  [image: Empty]
  [image: Empty]
  [image: SourceForge]
  :: [Christian Feuersänger](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/1537/christian-feuers%C3%A4nger)
- [image: Empty]
  [image: Empty]
  [image: CTAN]
  [image: GitHub]
  [image: Empty]
  [image: Empty]
  [image: Empty]
  :: [Paul Gaborit](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/14500)
- [image: Empty]
  [image: BitBucket]
  [image: CTAN]
  [image: GitHub]
  [image: Empty]
  [image: Empty]
  [image: Empty]
  :: [Paul Gessler](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/21344)
- [image: Empty]
  [image: Empty]
  [image: CTAN]
  [image: GitHub]
  [image: Empty]
  [image: Empty]
  [image: Empty]
  :: [Patrick Gundlach](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/243)
- [image: Empty]
  [image: Empty]
  [image: Empty]
  [image: GitHub]
  [image: Empty]
  [image: Empty]
  [image: Empty]
  :: [Patrick Gundlach (for Speedata)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/243)
- [image: Empty]
  [image: Empty]
  [image: Empty]
  [image: GitHub]
  [image: Empty]
  [image: Empty]
  [image: Empty]
  :: [David Haberthür](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/828/habi)<sup>1</sup>
- [image: Empty]
  [image: Empty]
  [image: Empty]
  [image: GitHub]
  [image: Empty]
  [image: Empty]
  [image: Empty]
  :: [Tom Hejda](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/11002) (yo')
- [image: Empty]
  [image: Empty]
  [image: CTAN]
  [image: GitHub]
  [image: Empty]
  [image: Empty]
  [image: Empty]
  :: [Michiel Helvensteijn](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/14886/mhelvens) (mhelvens)
- [image: Empty]
  [image: Empty]
  [image: CTAN]
  [image: GitHub]
  [image: Empty]
  [image: Empty]
  [image: Empty]
  :: [Michal Hoftich](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/2891)
- [image: Empty]
  [image: Empty]
  [image: CTAN]
  [image: GitHub]
  [image: Empty]
  [image: Empty]
  [image: Empty]
  :: [Chris Hughes (cmhughes)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/6621/cmhughes)
- [image: Empty]
  [image: Empty]
  [image: CTAN]
  [image: GitHub]
  [image: Empty]
  [image: Empty]
  [image: Empty]
  :: [Jubobs](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/21891/jubobs)
- [image: Empty]
  [image: Empty]
  [image: Empty]
  [image: GitHub]
  [image: Empty]
  [image: Empty]
  [image: Empty]
  :: [Matthew Leingang](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/1402)
- [image: Empty]
  [image: BitBucket]
  [image: Empty]
  [image: GitHub]
  [image: Empty]
  [image: Empty]
  [image: Empty]
  :: [Adam Liter](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/32888)
- [image: Empty]
  [image: Empty]
  [image: Empty]
  [image: GitHub]
  [image: Empty]
  [image: Empty]
  [image: Empty]
  :: [Mico Loretan](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/5001/mico) (mico)
- [image: Empty]
  [image: BitBucket]
  [image: CTAN]
  [image: GitHub]
  [image: Empty]
  [image: Empty]
  [image: Empty]
  :: [Clemens Niederberger](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/5049) (cgnieder)
- [image: Empty]
  [image: Empty]
  [image: CTAN]
  [image: GitHub]
  [image: Empty]
  [image: Empty]
  [image: Empty]
  :: [Joel C. Salomon](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/2966/j-c-salomon)
- [image: Empty]
  [image: Empty]
  [image: CTAN]
  [image: GitHub]
  [image: Empty]
  [image: Empty]
  [image: Empty]
  :: [samcarter](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/36296/samcarter)
- [image: Empty]
  [image: Empty]
  [image: CTAN]
  [image: GitHub]
  [image: Empty]
  [image: Empty]
  [image: Empty]
  :: [Simon Sigurdhsson](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/66)
- [image: Empty]
  [image: Empty]
  [image: CTAN]
  [image: GitHub]
  [image: Empty]
  [image: Empty]
  [image: Empty]
  :: [Thomas F. Sturm](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/30617/thomas-f-sturm)
- [image: Empty]
  [image: Empty]
  [image: CTAN]
  [image: GitHub]
  [image: Empty]
  [image: Empty]
  [image: Empty]
  :: [Nicola Talbot](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/19862/nicola-talbot)
- [image: Empty]
  [image: Empty]
  [image: Empty]
  [image: GitHub]
  [image: Empty]
  [image: Empty]
  [image: Empty]
  :: [Toby Thurston](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/15036/thruston) (thruston)
- [image: Empty]
  [image: Empty]
  [image: CTAN]
  [image: GitHub]
  [image: Empty]
  [image: Empty]
  [image: Empty]
  :: [Tobias Weh](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/4918)
- [image: Empty]
  [image: BitBucket]
  [image: CTAN]
  [image: GitHub]
  [image: Empty]
  [image: Empty]
  [image: Empty]
  :: [Sam Whited](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/10744/sam-whited)
- [image: Assembla]
  [image: BitBucket]
  [image: CTAN]
  [image: GitHub]
  [image: LaTeX2e]
  [image: LaTeX3]
  [image: SourceForge]
  :: [Joseph Wright](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/73)

---

<sup>1</sup> It includes the repository for his [LaTeX examples](https://github.com/habi/latex) and his [PhD-Thesis](https://github.com/habi/PhD-Thesis), which is available as PDF [here](http://wiki.davidhaberthuer.ch/_media/haberthuer2010.pdf).

Comment: *Must... put... this... list... in... alphabetical... order...* `:)` ♥

Comment: I've been thinking the same thing... drives me nuts (I tried once or twice, then I gave up)

Comment: Let's wait for someone with less control over his/her OCD than we have. `:)`

Comment: But now that you've said it I'm getting the itch again...

Comment: Be strong, my friend. `:)`

Comment: Ordering by first or last name? `:)`

Comment: I was doing last name

Comment: Is sorting by display name by cutting and pasting too easy?

Comment: @ChrisH Go for it!

Comment: @PauloCereda I'd like it in a jsortable table so I can order on first name, lastname or code repository, or an order than just puts me first anyway.

Comment: @David: ooh that would be awesome. `:)`

Comment: @PauloCereda Awesome edit!

Comment: @Jubobs: Thanks, it was a risky edit. `:)`

Comment: @PauloCereda There's always `revert` `:)`